# Need a minimal desktop-free system that boots and runs off a USB drive

Tags: boot, server, usb

I'm trying to create something simple: a USB that boots a live version of Linux that runs but doesn't need installation. I'd like to add a few utilities of my own and want it to be good old command line Unix with no graphical environment that supports persistence. The end product should be an .iso that I can give to others to burn on their own USBs and boot into any (typical 86-based) computer. Here's what I've tried:

1. Download a version of Ubuntu Server .iso
2. Use Cubic to modify the .iso to add in the utilities I want to include
3. Cubic spits out a new MyBootable.iso with Ubuntu Server + my utilities
4. Use Rufus to write MyBootable.iso to a USB. I can use persistance with this write.
5. Boot from this USB
6. Ubuntu starts and wants to install itself onto the hard drive
7. Run the system from the hard drive - it runs beautifully

This **almost** meets my needs. The problem is that step 6 forces me to install the system since the only "Try It" version of Ubuntu is packaged with Ubuntu Desktop - something I want to avoid.

What can I do to create a MyBootable.iso that meets all of my needs?

Do I choose a different flavor of Linux in step 1? I chose Ubuntu Server because it works on just about any hardware whether BIOS of UEFI.

Is there something I can do between steps 1 + 2 to make this happen?

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I don't have a PC to test, and you could probably write an OS yourself faster than my phone would work through the process, but [Live CD Customization From Scratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) seems like what you're after.

Comment: You could set up system as you like it then use Disks or Clonezilla to make an image file. Image files can be flashed USB's or HDD's using Rufus or Disks or mkusb.